# How can I write a function that returns any object derived from a base class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a base class, say A.

From that base class I have derived a bunch of other classes, say A1, A2, A3 ...

I have a third class, say B. One of the methods it has needs to be able to return any class as long as it is derived from A.

I tried the following:

```
public T getObject<T>() where T : A
{
   return (new A1());
}
```

However this returns an error that says cannot convert type A1 to T.

Can this generic return be implemented?

Comment: why not `return new T()` ?

Comment: it's not a generic if you return `A1`

Comment: I want to be able to construct either of A1, A2 or A3 because they have very different construction logic in the "getObject" method and then return that object.

However, the object that invokes "getObject" can use the fact that all these classes are derived from A to implement a method common to them all.

Comment: why use a generic method at all then? Just use `A` as the return type

Comment: What purpose `T` is being used for?

Answer (score 2):

If you know your class will inherit from A, but don't need to know the exact type then you don't need generics:

```
public A getObject()
{
    return new A1();
}
```

If your example had compiled that would mean you could call

```
A2 result = getObject<A2>();
```

But your implementation of `getObject` always returns a `new A1()`. Since `A1` doesn't inherit `A2` this is would be wrong.

It sounds like you might want to return different types depending on the result of some mystery logic. This is fine, there's still no need for generics:

```
public A getObject()
{
    switch(MysteryLogic())
    {
        case MysteryLogicResult.One:
            return new A1();
        case MysteryLogicResult.Two:
            return new A2();
        case MysteryLogicResult.Three:
            return new A3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to combine this with a factory:

```
public interface IAFactory
{
    A Build();
}
```

Then you can change your generic method:

```
public A getObject<T>() where T : new, IAFactory
{
    return getObject(new T()
}

public A getObject<T>(T factory) where T : IAFactory
{
    return factory.Build();
}
```

You'll need to change your implementation of A1, A2:

```
public class A1 : A, IAFactory
{
   public A1 Build(){
      //Logic for constructing A1
   }
}
```

Or create a dedicated class:

```
public class A1Factory : IAFactory
{
   public A1 Build(){
      //Logic for constructing A1
   }
}
```

Then you can call your method:

```
public class Test
{
  public void CallBMethod()
  {
     //option 1
     A option1 = new B().getObject<A1>();

     //option 2
     A option2 = new B().getObject<A1Factory>();

    //Or skip the B.getObject method and access factory directly:
    A a1 = new A1Factory().Build();
    A a2 = new A2Factory().Build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: You have to return T because that's the return type you declared for your method.**

If you return A1, it looks like it should work as you stated.  But you forgot that you can also call the method by passing in A2, in which case return A1 is not valid:

```
var myObject = getObject<A1>(); // this would have worked
var myObject = getObject<A2>(); // this can not work
```

This will fail, because A1 is not assignable to the type A2.  Because the 2nd case cannot work, the compiler will not allow you to do that.

So then the correct way would be to return new T instead:

```
public T getObject<T>() where T : A
{
   return (new T());
}

var myObject = getObject<A1>(); // works
var myObject = getObject<A2>(); // also works
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use factory pattern to get desired results:

```
public A GetObject (string type) {
     A aObj ;
     if (type == "A1") {
        aobj = new A1 () ;
     else if (type == "A2") {
         aobj = new A2 () ;
     }
     return aObj ;
}
```

Comment: I would advise against this strategy.  Referencing types by their `Type.Name` like this is a code smell.  You are breaking compile time checking.  For example, what happens when you rename `A1` to `A-HasABetterNameNow-1`.  You'll have to remember to go back and update this string literal.

Comment: You are correct. I just want to present idea and it can be improved in many ways. I think your answer is comprehensive.